# Internationalisation in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization, react-i18next, next-i18next

I am trying to put together a NextJS project that needs i18n. I found multiple libraries regarding i18n. Do we really need to those ?
Though I went through documentations, maintaining an Object at global level and retrieving it based on locale info from NextJS using some kind of logic feel easier. Is there any specific use-case these libraries are trying to solve ? Am I missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct! You can totally simply create a global object and retrieve based on the locale

I personally use [next-translate](https://github.com/aralroca/next-translate) simply because of:

- Speed (SEO): I want my bundle size small ( each locale should only get the translations that the combination of page and locale will use )
- It includes a function to log missing keys by default
- Formaters ( ex.: numbers )
- Syntax: I like the "useTranslation" hook and seems easy for future devs to read, also it gets the current locale by itself so just one readable line
- Nice syntax for variables and including dynamic components inside the translations
- Easy pluralization

But if you don't have many translations and they don't need complex use cases go with the global object and you will be fine, its totally okay